# how to allow the user to enter a file name and prompt an error message if the file cannot be opened in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

how to allow the user to enter a file name and prompt an error message if the file cannot be opened in python

i have tried with normal read mode however when I try with user input it does not work

Comment: please show your attempted code - thanks :)

Comment: _however when I try with user input it does not work_ Show us.  Otherwise we can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: when i tried this      with open ("example1.txt") as file:
    print(file.read()) it worked fine due to me pre entering the file name however since i want to be able to do it once the code is running i tried this  
user_input = input("Enter the file to read:")
file = user_input + ".txt"

print (file)  it just adds .txt to the entered file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

The first way is to use a **try-except** clause like this:

#### Code:

```
try:
    file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        # Process the file
        contents = f.read()  # read the contents of the file
        print(contents)  # print the contents of the file
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Error: File not found.")
except:
    print("Some other exception occurred")
```

Or you can use the **[path.exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?#os.path.exists)** function from the **os** package:

#### Code:

```
import os

file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
if os.path.exists(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        # Process the file
        contents = f.read()  # read the contents of the file
        print(contents)  # print the contents of the file
else:
    print("Error: File not found.")
```

Comment: using the path.exist function code how would i be able to output the contents of the .txt file?

Comment: see updated code to print the contents of the file